# Replacing individual characters in a print statement

Tags: python

**I know the title is quite vague, but I have no idea how to sum what I want to do.**

An example is a loading screen, I want to do something like this:

```
Loading assets - 10%
```

and then remove the output from the terminal and print

```
Loading textures - 20%
```

Every time I try something like this I get

```
Loading assets - 10%
Loading textures - 20%
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can I suggest you to adopt some kind of library for this, like [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm), instead of writing your own stuff?

Comment: For which kind of operating system and terminal do you want this to work? Windows default `cmd` has quite different requirements for this than must UNIX terminals.

Answer (score 0):

Use os package and clear screen and rewrite every update time.

```
import os
os.system("clear")
print "your text"
```

Comment: That would work but I have other things on the screen that I don't want to clear, are there any  other solutions?

Comment: probably you need this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520120/overwriting-clearing-previous-console-line

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you could be using python 3.3+ the print statement can help you with this:

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

So when printing use:

```
print('Mytext', flush=True)
```

Comment: i have question , can this script run on python 2-x?

Comment: @SkillerDz No, thus the assumption:)

Answer (score 0):

try this script ; i tested it and it work fine , i added time.sleep for you see the effects

```
import os
from platform import system
import time


if system() == 'Windows':
   os.system('cls')
if system() == 'Linux':
   os.system('cls')

print("Loading Images - 10%")

time.sleep(2)

if system() == 'Windows':
   os.system('cls')
if system() == 'Linux':
   os.system('cls')

print("Loading Texture - 20%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear and simple solution for Python 3

```
import sys, time
for x in (10, 20, 30):
    print("Loading assets - {}%".format(x), end="\r")
    time.sleep(2)
```

For good measure, you may want to add a `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print`. This works on UNIXes at least…